# Updating Textview Without Blocking UI in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have to Render 2000 lines of text String into Textview in Flutter.
I have used `setState((){ textString = "2000 lines of String...."; })`
And used textString within Text().
but Application freezing UI for more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved with asynchronous programming.

```
String textString = "";

  Future<void> _renderText(String str) async{
    setState(() {
      textString = str;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _renderText('2000line of String...');
    super.initState();
  }
```

If you use the button

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
                 await _renderText('2000line of String...');
            },
  child: Text('Update'),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank a lot for answering.
here i am used async and received data without issue.
while updating text in Text view its freezing application for few seconds.

Container(child:Text( textString));

Comment: I used async, but it still gets stuck in the update process??

Comment: its consuming more time to update TextView, at this stage Application is freezing.

Comment: i think so you have to `isolate` 
This part has not been cleared yet. I'll edit my answer as soon as it clears up about `ioslate`.

Answer (score 0):

"As per my observation data which is need to be updated to view is huge and its taking time to update at this case Application is crashing.
For this am using pagination concept like split into multiple pieces and updating to View.

Ex: here am using length of the string, set maximum length of string to update view, based on this length splitting and updating view."